# Find the Laurent Series centered at $z=0$ for all the analitical region of $\frac{\sinh(z) - z}{z^4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent Series centered at $z=0$ for all the analitical region of

$\frac{\sinh(z) - z}{z^4}$

Comment: Have you considered the MacLaurin series expansion for $\sinh z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: consider the Taylor- series for $sinh.$

Step 2: subtract $z$.

Step 3: now divide by by $z^4.$

Whoops, the  Laurent Series centered at $z=0$  is completed.

This series converges on $ \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$